# using 'the same as' to liken two actions

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

Is the usage of 'the same as' in the following sentence correct?

> Jack does to Fanny exactly **the same as** what Fanny has done to him.

If not, what's the idiomatic way in English to express the idea that the first action, which is described in the first clause, is just identical to the one described in the second clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The correct expression would delete the "what":
"Jack does to Fanny exactly the same as Fanny has done to him."

To keep that "what", you would need put another at the start of the sentence:
"What Jack does to Fanny is exactly the same as what Fanny has done to him."